# I'm not sure use which algorithm to solve the route-plan problem? And how to use java to finish it?

Tags: java, algorithm

This question I met when I finish my final year project. I'm not good at route planning algorithm. So, please help me.

The questions:

How should i get the most efficient way to solve the final year project?
Do you have any tips?
I mean I search the relative topic in IEEE and other Academic conference website, and there are
so many resouces, I browse for a long time but I still don't know how to solve my problem.

Waht algorithm should I use to solve the above problem? I mean
Can I use the VPR Algorithm(vechicle routing problem) and heuristic method to solve it?

Q; In a town, how to design bus route according to the requirement of users?

For example, there are points a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h in this town. 
   The time-require is different between these points, which can be obseved on figure 1 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/663ZZ.png).

A-B: 2 mins
   B-C: 4 mins
   C-D: 2 mins
   A-F: 3 mins
   B-F: 4 mins
   F-G: 2 mins
   B-G: 3 mins
   C-G: 2 mIns
   C-H: 4 mins
   G-H: 3 mins
   D-H: 3 mins

Every minute people arrive each points.

For point "a", every minute, seven people come by car, but each person's destination is random point from b,c,d,e,f,g,h, except a.

For point "b", every minute, six people come by car, and their destination is random point from a,c,d,e,f,g,h, except b.

For point "c", every minute, four people come by car, and their destination is random point from a,b,d,e,f,g,h, except c.

For point "d", every minute, five people come by car, and their destination is random point from a,b,c,e,f,g,h, except d.

For point "e", every minute, four people come by car, and their destination is random point from a,b,c,d,f,g,h, except e.

For point "f", every minute, seven people come by car, and their destination is random point from a,b,c,d,e,g,h, except f.

For point "g", every minute, two people come by car, and their destination is random point from a,b,c,d,e,f,h, except g.

For point "h", every minute, two people come by car, and their destination is random point from a,b,c,d,e,f,g, except h.

How to generate the optomal bus line?( The bus route line format should look like: A->F->B->G->H->C->D. )